# Is it possible to stringify parameters in ruby/irb?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby ... wondering if the following is possible:

I currently run a test app within irb (irb -r test.rb) and manually execute
various command implemented in test.rb.  One of these functions is currently implemented as follows:

```
def cli(cmd)
  ret=$client.Cli(cmd)
  print ret, "\n"
end
```

Where `$client.Cli()` takes a string.  I currently type the following in the IRB prompt
`> cli "some command with parameters"`

This is sent over socket and results are returned

I would like to be able to do this WITHOUT the quotes.  This would be just for this command
Is there a way to do this generally in ruby?  if not how would you extend irb to do this?

For those who know 'C' this would be like the following:

```
#define CLI(CMD) cli(#CMD)
CLI(Quadafi and Sheen walk into a bar...)
```

where the pre-processed output is:

```
cli("Quadafi and Sheen walk into a bar...")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually monkey patch the `gets` method of the `IRB::StdioInputMethod` and `IRB::ReadlineInputMethod` classes, and perform a rewrite if the `cli` method is called, by adding the following to your `test.rb` file:

```
module IRB
  def self.add_quotes(str)
    str.gsub(/^cli (..+?)(\\+)?$/, 'cli "\1\2\2"') unless str.nil?
  end

  class StdioInputMethod
    alias :old_gets :gets

    def gets
      IRB::add_quotes(old_gets)
    end
  end

  class ReadlineInputMethod
    alias :old_gets :gets

    def gets
      IRB::add_quotes(old_gets)
    end
  end
end
```

This way, any input line matching `cli ...` will be replaced with `cli "..."` before it's evaluated.

Comment: Did some more 'unit testing' and some trouble and the line ends with '~' or '.'.  This is in no way critical, but I wonder if there is any way to make sure these get added to the string?  Is the problem at higher levels prior to Context's evaluate?

Comment: Now it handles the line endings you mention. However, if you enter `cli test\ `, the replacement results in `cli "test\"`, e.g. the final `"` is escaped, and irb wants you to complete the string on the following line(s).

Comment: Final edition handles any number of trailing backslashes as well. Quotes still have to be escaped, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, because the command that you type to irb has to parse as ruby, and all those bare words will report errors like this:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object
```

(My first attempt, I just called it via `cli hello`.)

But if you didn't mind a more radical change, you could do something like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/test_cases
hello world
one
two
three
riding the corpse sled

$ ruby -e 'def f(arg) puts arg end' -ne 'f($_)' < /tmp/test_cases
hello world
one
two
three
riding the corpse sled
```

I just defined a simple function `f()` here that would show how it works; you could replace `f($_)` with `$Client.cli($_)`, and set up the `$Client` global variable in the first `-e` argument. And you can leave off the `< /tmp/test_cases` if you want to type them in interactively:

```
$ ruby -e 'def f(arg) puts arg end' -ne 'f($_)'
hello
hello
world
world
```

Of course, if you want it to be any more advanced than this, I'd just write a script to do it all, rather than build something hideous from `-pe` or `-ne` commands.